# Unable to find Element via XPath Selector for type text with no name or Id

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

Chrome Inspect

[image: Using Chrome]

The Code in C#

```
IWebElement Search =
   driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@placeholder='search' and
   @type='text']"));
       Actions actions_Search = new Actions(driver);
       actions_Search.MoveToElement(Search).Click().SendKeys("ABCDEFG").Perform();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

xpath that you should check :

```
//input[contains(@class,'searchbox') and @placeholder='search' @type='text']
```

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If we have unique entry 1/1 then you can use the following code :

```
IWebElement elem = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//input[contains(@class,'searchbox') and @placeholder='search' @type='text']")).SendKeys("ABCDEFG");
```

I am not certain why exactly you need an action class for this.

Comment: thanks for your help you need to put one more and between this @placeholder='search' @type='text'

Answer (score 2):

Mostly, then you can't find element by xpath but the element is exist, is probably because it exist in different iframe

check location of element in browser from top level element by code (in chrome console):

```
$x("//input")
```

then if it is not found, switch to different iframe like this:
[image]

Then use iframe switch in your code

Comment: yes this situation is also correct so voted up